# Dynamics CRM 2013: Workflow designer Boolean & Optionset Fields set values disappearing

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

Background: I'm a sys admin running on CRM 2013 SP1 RU 3

Whenever I set a Boolean or Optionset field (text fields seem to be fine) value via the workflow designer, the values I previously set disappear from the designer.

For example when I initially set the values I see this:
[image]

Then after I hit save & close and click on "set properties" again I see this:

[image]

However, when I export the solution and open the workflow xaml file I can clearly see:

```
<InArgument x:TypeArguments="s:Object[]" x:Key="Parameters">[New Object() {    Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.WorkflowPropertyType.Boolean, "True" }]</InArgument>
```

Which suggests to me that the value is being set but it is just not showing up in the Workflow designer.

I found that if I move the field back ON the form (I.e. not have the field sitting in the "Additional Fields" section) then the value displays as per normal.

Can anyone explain to me what is happening and if it's something that can be resolved on my end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to click the value inside the designer (left panel) but the default value inside the Form Assistant (right panel) and after click OK.

Your selection inside the left panel will become yellow, meaning is applied inside your workflow.

Comment: Sure that will force the value to display but is that the only way to achieve this?

It feels like a bug given that the values will display if you move the field onto the form

Comment: the workflow designer always worked in this way, if you don't like the way it works send a feedback using the Microsoft Connect site.